# How to use linux path in eclipse cdt?

Tags: makefile, eclipse-cdt

I wrote in my Makefile:

```
GCC := i386-elf-gcc
```

and use it to build my project.

But when I click my 'build' button, the eclipse cdt console gets an error:

```
make all 
make: i386-elf-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [boot/bootmain.o] Error 1
```

I use mac os. and the path of i386-elf-gcc:

```
zsh> which i386-elf-gcc                                           
/usr/local/bin/i386-elf-gcc
```

In my `/etc/paths` there has `/usr/local/bin`.
So I wonder how to fix this problem?? Thank you!

Comment: Does your `PATH` environment variable contain `/usr/local/bin`? How are you launching Eclipse? Try launching Eclipse from the same shell in which you ran that `which` command.

Comment: @HighCommander4 You're right!! It works! But how to fix it when I open Eclipse in my finder.. This works whenever in terminal or in zsh. But when I open it in finder, it will still wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know, macOS is not my strong suit. I would recommend asking a new and more targeted question, like "How do I change variables in the default environment in which applications opened from Finder run?"

Comment: Really Thanks! I'll try this.