# How do I change variables in the default environment in which applications opened from Finder run?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, eclipse-cdt, finder

I noticed when I open an .app program in Finder, the environment variables are very different from when I open in terminal or zsh. As my eclipse-cdt:

In my Makefile, I use a `GCC := i386-elf-gcc` to compile my .c. `> which i386-elf-gcc` in terminal shows `> /usr/local/bin`.

When I open eclipse-cdt in zsh or terminal use shell command `> open /Applications/Eclipse.cpp`, I enter into my project and press `build` button. And it compiles perfectly.

However, when I open eclipse-cdt in my Finder, similarly click the `build` button, I got an error as follow:

```
make all 
make: i386-elf-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [boot/bootmain.o] Error 1
```

I'd like to know how could I do it. And thanks for a buddy that he told me to ask the question. Link: [How to use linux path in eclipse cdt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404405/how-to-use-linux-path-in-eclipse-cdt)

Sincerely thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: 1) You seem to use C++, why use the C tag then? 2) This is not about a programming language or programming, but system configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)